# Deserialization of Objects in C++ in the Constructor

Tags: c++, serialization, deserialization

It is a good practice to deserialize object using a overloaded constructor in C++ or it is better to create a member function deserialize(std::istream& file)?

Comment: Could you please mark one of the answers as the solution, or if you believe this doesn't answer your question, elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. You avoid two-step initialization and all problems caused by it. Some opjects don't make sense to exist "uninitialized". Thus at least in such cases, you should put the serialization code into the constructor. The advantage of this design is, that you can use the same constructor for reading and writing. And you're unable to violate the order of initializing of base classes or member classes. The only disadvantage is that for writing you temporarily create a copy of the object to be written to somewhere. If this turns out to be a problem, you can still copy the constructor code into some write method. Of course you should be part of the current century and use exception handling for errors when reading and writing. And you really want to make the CReadWrite class constructable from some abstract CRead and CWrite, so that you can read and write from/to "somewhere", including files, pipes, sockets, memory buffer, and who knows what your customers are going to come up the day after tomorrow.

```
struct CReadWrite;

struct A:B
{   std::string m_sName; 
    A(const A *const pWrite, CReadWrite *const pFile)
        :B(pWrite ? static_cast<B*>(pWrite) : 0, pFile),
        m_sName(pFile->readWrite(pWrite ? &pWrite->m_sName : 0))
    {
    }
};
```

reading:

```
CReadWrite sFile("test.dat", "r");
A sA(0, &sFile);
```

writing:

```
CReadWrite sFile("test.dat", "w");
A sA;
A(&sA, &sFile);
```

Answer (score 5):

I would advise creating a separate deserialiser function as it seperates the responsibility (i.e. the constructor doesn't need to worry about how it gets its information).

**For example**

```
class Foo
{
    Foo(int x)
    ...
}

Foo FooDeserialiser(Data data)
{
    // get data to pass to constructor
    return Foo(someInt);
}
```

You *could* make a member function, but I personally prefer to keep it seperate from the class (although I often put it in the same file) as to me this would be breaking the encapsulation.

Comment: +1. But if the public constructor is not flexible enough, or the class is not amenable to a factory function, then a deserializing constructor is a good idea.

Comment: First you create an uninitialized car and then you flesh it out. If the fleshing out fails, you have the possibility of accidentally trying to use the uninitialized car for driving...

Comment: +1. @Potatoswatter: Of course, the deserialiser should be designed together with the class being constructed; it could be made a friend function, or a static member function.

Answer (score 1):

Putting deserialization in the constructor may limit your flexibility in how you handle failure cases (e.g. corrupt input data).  A dedicated member function is more flexible.  For example, it allows you to `return` a status value, whereas the constructor cannot return a value to indicate failure.  Whether you need this flexibility at the cost of losing [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) is up to you.

Comment: A constructor should throw an exception to indicate failure. If this is proven to be a performance bottleneck, you can add the status value into the class as a field, or add it to the constructor as an out-parameter.

Comment: @GrapschKnutsch Please clarify your comment. Do you disagree with the assertion in the answer, or the basis that flexibility to return a status value is valuable?

Comment: I'm creating objects since years using single step initialization using the constructor. That somebody trying to teach others is still using two step initialization today, makes me curious. That you don't know how to abort a constructor today is even more bothersome.

Comment: @GrapschKnutsch Clarified my answer to include the downside to two-step. Regarding aborting constructors, is there a way to do this without exceptions? If not, then there are cases where two-step is still warranted, since there are projects that prohibit the use of exceptions. Just because something exists in the C++ standard does not mean it should always be used.